# CSS aligning element

Tags: css

I hate CSS, because always hard to predict what it will render into. Can you guys help me to fix this thing...

I need the right side of elements in dropdown menu aligned right under the arrow. First I thought if I do `position:absolute`, and then just move `left` to number of pixels, it will work, but if the username changes it breaks everything again

here's the fiddle for your convenience

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwd2A/1/

thank you

Comment: be careful of that down arrow that is not enclosed in a tag. It might not work as expected cross - browser. I would put it into a span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to when hovering the arrow, that submenu appears right aligned with the arrow.

If it is that:
Add css attribute to .userSubmenu

```
position: relative;
```

Add css attributes to .userSubmenu ul

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mwd2A/5/

Comment: It works on the context of what you put in the jsfiddle, hope it works in the real context.